# I'm trying to create a regex for a strong password

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I'm having some trouble creating a regex for a password. It has the following requirements :

- at least 10 characters
- at least 1 uppercase letter
- at least 1 lowercase letter
- at least 1 special character

I currently created this line :
`

```
"^(?=(.*[A-Z])+)(?=(.*[a-z])+)(?=(.*[0-9])+)(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()_+=.])+){10,}$"
```

`
For a password like : Lollypop56@
it still gives me false.

Comment: What you describe is a __weak__ password. A 'strong' password is one that an automated cracker tool cannot crack. "Must have a number" is lovely, as a cracking tool, that makes things easier, not harder. "A number must be in there" reduces the search space: 95%+ of users stick either a '1' on the end, the year of their birth on the end, the year of signup on the end, or, rarely, replace an 'i' with a '1' or an 'a' with a 4 or an 'e' with a 3. See NIST recommendations. This is horrible, horrible security.

Comment: You must have a second factor such as TOTP for proper security. For pw rules: at least 8, that's good enough. If you want more, install jack-the-cracker or similar software and have it run spare CPU cycles against your pw db. If it cracks one, next time that user logs in, tell them they have to change their pass.

Comment: Example extremely powerful password: "walk vase bind red". This has _vastly_ more entropy than anything 8 characters. And your silly argument would consider that 'weak', proving the point. See [here](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Other truths few know about: "Must have a special character" -> That means there it'll be an exclamation point over 90% of the time, and it'll appear at the end, or just before the mandatory digit. "Must have a capital" -> The first letter will be capitalized. All of this reduces entropy, i.e. is stupid as a password restriction. There's value in enforcing a 'good password', sure. But 'must have a capital letter' does not accomplish the goal of finding a good password!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a full point after the lookahead of special characters. So it would be:

```
"^(?=(.*[A-Z])+)(?=(.*[a-z])+)(?=(.*[0-9])+)(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()_+=.])+).{10,}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you that use https://www.passay.org/. This dependency able you to validate wide range of password policy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the `+` in the groups inside the lookaheads since those aren't needed and also make those groups non-capturing. I'd also not explicitly specify the characters in the "special" group. Just make it match any of the characters *not* in the first three groups, `[^A-Za-z0-9]`. That'll allow `~` as a special character too etc.

Also, the actual matching should be `.{10,}`, not `{10,}`.

```
"^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]))(?=(?:.*[a-z]))(?=(?:.*[0-9]))(?=(?:.*[^A-Za-z0-9])).{10,}$"
```